# JavaScript можно ли при клике по строке (тег p) узнать номер буквы в этой строке по которому кликнули и как?

Tags: javascript, html, браузер

Есть некоторая строка в которой текст:

```
<p>Вот некоторая строка.</p>
```

Вопрос можно ли используя JavaScript отследить событие клика по этой строке и определить номер буквы(или символа если учитывать пробелы и прочее) по которой кликнули. Или определить слово по которому кликнули если такой функционал есть.

P.S. Я понимаю что можно все символы в строке разметить используя span например так:

```
<span>б</span><span>у</span><span>к</span><span>в</span><span>а</span>
```

Интересует можно ли без таких действий как то сделать.

Если кому интересно, пока что я придумал загружать html как есть а при наведении мышки размечать буквы в span, а когда фокус с строки снимается возвращать обратно.

На вопрос зачем мне вообще это: ищу варианты для визуального редактора.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41770502/can-i-get-one-symbol-from-string-after-clicking только подобное я нашел

Comment: второй вопрос: а зачем именно так? в визуальном редакторе никто не парится подобным, ибо это нафиг не нужно. если речь о том, чтобы, например, сделать активными кнопки на тулбаре в зависимости от положения курсора в форматированном тексте, то достаточно отследить сам элемент, в который кликнули, безотносительно конкретного символа в нем.

Comment: Попробуйте [Selection.anchorOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/anchorOffset) — щелчок на элементе с текстом создаёт выделение нулевой длины (схлопнутое), так что можно получить расстояние начала этого выделения от начала текста элемента.